# What's the difference between 'coil' and 'coil around'?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

There are two sentences like this.

1. The snake coiled the dog.
2. The snake coiled around the dog.

What's the difference between 'round' and 'shot at'in meaning?

I think that the sentence is the same. but Why do they use 'around' next coil? Please, tell me the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The snake coiled the dog" is wrong; "the snake coiled around the dog" is correct.

**[Coil](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coil)** can be used transitively or intransitively.

Used transitively, it means "to arrange in loops, rings, or spirals", so "the snake coiled the dog" means that the snake made the dog into loops!

Used intransitively, it means "to form loops, rings, or spirals", so "the snake coiled" means that the snake made loops of itself, and "around the dog" is a prepositional phrase describing the way in which it did so.

Answer (score 1):

You can coil a line (a rope used on a boat).

If your coil a rope, the rope ends up in loops **with nothing at its center**.

However, **if you coil a rope around something**, you make the loops with the rope around the the thing or person or animal. **The object is then at the center of the loops.**